# Проверка наличия файлов

Tags: bash

Необходимо проверить наличие файлов, список которых содержится в ещё одном файле.
При запуске скрипта выходит слишком большой листинг - как его сократить только до отсутствующих файлов и перенаправиль его в файл?

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=`cat /home/.dir/file.orig | awk '{print $2}'`
if ! [ -f $FILE ]; then
   echo "The File '$FILE' Does Not Exist" >> /varlog/start.log
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть awk сформирует список команд для проверки и потом bash их выполнит

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file.orig | awk '{print "[ ! -f ", $2,"] && echo file ",$2," not exist"}' | bash >> /varlog/start.log
```

Второй вариант - с использованием цикла

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `cat file.orig | awk '{print $2}'`
do
 if [ ! -f $f ]; then
  echo "The File '$f' Does Not Exist"
 fi
done
```

Comment: А как с эту конструкцию добавить exit 0 при удачном выполнении? У меня постоянно exit 1.

Comment: А что значит "неудачное выполнение". может к самому концу строки дописать `&& exit 0`

Comment: Я понял абсурдность своего вопроса.

Лучше объясню полностью задачу: необходимо провести пречек в скрипте перед выполнением основной части, соответственно проверка файлов должна закончиться либо удачно и скрипт будет выполняться дальше, либо же проверка не удастся, тогда нужно список не найденых файлов передать в ерор лог и завершить скрипт с кодо 1.

Comment: @Andrey поправил ответ, сделал вариант с циклом, можете в этом цикле при ошибке взвести переменную по которой после цикла сбросить лог куда следует и менять логику остального выполнения

Comment: @Andrey И как вариант мой первый вариант с направлением в файл, только с 1й `>` и после него `if [ -s file.log ]` т.е. проверка лога на не нулевую длину

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Первый вариант для меня пока более сложный, но в копилку для разбора забрал, а вот второй именно то, что я пытался соорудить, но немного не хватило знаний или логики.